# Spring Security MockMVC @AuthenticationPrincipal at CustomUserDetails param is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, mockmvc

I am using spring security and trying to test with mockMvc.
And I'm using @AuthenticationPrincipal and I've newly created CustomUserDetails.
But this doesn't work in a test environment what should I do?

```
fun getTreasures(
        @AuthenticationPrincipal userDetails: CustomUserDetails?,
    )

@Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "myUser", roles = ["MEMBER"])
    fun getTreasures() {
        val uri = "/api/adventure/treasures"

        mockMvc.get(uri) {
            header("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.authentication(authenticationWithCustomUserDetails()))
        }
            .andDo {
                print()
            }
            .andExpect {
                status { isOk() }
            }
            .andReturn()
    }
```

and my error

```
CustomUserDetails': codes []; arguments []; default message [Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.realworld.adventure.common.security.service.CustomUserDetails.<init>, parameter id]] ]

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = Invalid request content.
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
Expected :200
Actual   :400
```

my CustomUserDetails

```
class CustomUserDetails(
    private val id: String,
    private val username: String,
    private val role: String?,
) : UserDetails {
```

spring Security is not worked